# Find the locus of points |z-1|= -Im(z).

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, locus

If I wish to find the locus of complex points satisfying $ |z-1|= -\text{Im}(z)$, then would I be right in supposing it represents the half-circle
$(x-1)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1/4, y \leq 0$?

My work follows:

1. First, notice $|z-1| \geq 0 \Rightarrow \text{Im}(z) \leq 0.$
2. Second,
   $$|z-1|^2 = (-\text{Im}(z))^2 \Rightarrow |z|^2 - 2\text{Re}(z)+ 1 = \text{Im}(z) \\ \Rightarrow x^2 +y^2 - 2x - y + 1 =0  \\ \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1/4,$$
   in completing the square.
   As $y = \text{Im}(z)$, we further restrict $y \leq 0.$

Comment: Geometrically, in the complex plane, it is those points whose distance from $1$ is equal to the distance below the real axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

You are on the right track, but you forgot to square $\text{Im}(z)$. If we let $z = x + yi$, it results that
\begin{align*}
|z - 1| = -\text{Im}(z) = -y & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
|z - 1|^{2} = y^{2}\\\\
y\leq 0
\end{cases}\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
|z|^{2} - 2\text{Re}(z) + 1 = y^{2}\\\\
y\leq 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + y^{2} - 2x + 1 = y^{2}\\\\
y\leq 0
\end{cases}\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(x - 1)^{2} = 0\\\\
y\leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Therefore, it consists of $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) = \pm 1, Im(z) \leq 0\}.$ Geometrically, this would correspond to two 'semi-infinite lines', extending at $x = +1 $ and $x = -1$ from $-\infty$ to $0$.

Comment: @VeraLeighton Notice that $(x - 1)^{2} = 0$ implies that $x = 1$. So the geometric interpretation is the half-line starting at $(1,0)$ and going downwards.

Answer (score 0):

From the given definition, we know that $y$ must be negative. Thus, $z$ must lie on the lower half plane.

A geometric approach would be like : Distance between $z$ and $(1,0)$ is equal to it's distance from real axis. Thus, $z$ must lie on the straight line $Re(z)= 1$ because a hypotenuse is always greater than other sides of right triangle.

[image]